# diff b\w any, many and exists in Ruby language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are the difference between `any?`, `many?`  and `exists?`? All three are checking whether a table is empty.

```
User.exists?
=> false
User.any?
=> false
User.many?
=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

First off .exists? and .many? are extensions provided through Rails, while .any? is Ruby.

**.any?**

.any? provides for versatility other than checking wether something is empty.  For example:

```
%w[ant bear cat].any? { |word| word.length >= 3 } #=> true
```

we can pass a block to the any method to find see where the collect has any of the item we are looking for.

**.many?**

.many checks to see if there are more than one.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].many? # => true
[].many? # => false
[1].many # => false
[1,2,3,4].many? { |o| o.multiple_of?(2) }
```

Think of it like an alias of collection.size > 1

**.exists?**

.exists sees if a record is there matching the conditions provided

```
  Person.exists?(5)
  Person.exists?('5')
  Person.exists?(:name => "David")
  Person.exists?(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"])
```

This is a bit more specific than .any.

**.empty?**
If you want to see if a String, Hash, or Array is empty you can call .empty on it.

Answer (score 1):

**exists?**

Will return true if there is atleast one record with the given conditions. you can pass in id or conditions

```
exists?(id_or_conditions = {}) public
```

exists uses `find_initial` internally which issues a query with the given conditions and limit 1

Eg:

```
User.exists? #SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" LIMIT 1
User.exists?(2) #SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
User.exists?(:name => "name") #SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'usha' LIMIT 1
```

**any?**

Will return true if there is `atleast one record`. Doesn't take any parameter

Eg:

```
User.any? # SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
```

**many?**

Will return true if there are `more than one record`. Doesn't take any paramenter

Eg:

```
User.many? #SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
```

Answer (score 0):

**User.any?**

```
User.any?  ##  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members"
```

Returns `true` if there are records present in Users table. That means, it will return `true` only if there are `1 or more` records in Users table and `false` otherwise.

**User.many?**

```
User.many?  ## SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
```

Returns `true` if there is `more than one` record in Users table. That means, it will return `false` if number of records in User table are `0 or 1`.

**User.exists?(conditions = :none)**

```
User.exists? ## SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" LIMIT 1
```

Returns `true` if at least one record exists in the Users table that matches the `id or conditions` given, `false` otherwise. This one takes 0..1 argument.

Eg(with conditions):

```
User.exists?(1)  ## SELECT 1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
User.exists?(name: 'XYZ')  ##SELECT 1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE "members"."name" = 'XYZ' LIMIT 1
```